# В чем разница между тремя записями объявления строки

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели

В чем разница между тремя записями:

1. `char* str = "hello";`
2. `char arr[] = "hello";`
3. `char chars[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };`

Comment: Третий вариант не является *строкой*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Первая строка обычно не компилируется современными компиляторами с++ - происходит попытка присвоить указателю  константные данные. По факту объявляется указатель, который указывает на константную строку (массив символов), которые компилятор где то разместит самостоятельно. Попытка модифицировать элементы строки по такому указателю обычно приводят к проблемам в runtime. Поэтому, лучше писать так `const char* str = "hello";` Но в си компилируется и просто объявляется указатель на строку, которая сохраняется отдельно.
- В втором случае объявляется массив на 6 элементов (последний - ноль). Обычная классическая си строка.
- В третьем случае создается массив на 5 элементов (без нулевого в конце). Если в самый конец добавить ещё один символ `'\0'` - то будет идентично второму варианту.

**UPD (но он для с++)**

По поводу "обычно не компилируется". Я понимаю, что стандарт требует, что бы это не компилировалось. И если компилятор следует букве закона, то он ругнется. Но... Есть такая опция [/Zc:strictStrings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=vs-2017). И по умолчанию она выключена... И это разрешает компилироваться первому варианту. Более того, ее ещё и не всегда так просто включить. К примеру, если используется Windows SDK.

Но может это только студийный компилятор так поступает? нет, gcc 7* и clang 7* просто ругаются, но компилируют! Самое интересное, что intel c++ compiler даже не ругнулся.

Да, в нормальных проектах накручены опции предупреждений, если это возможно. И утверждать, что нормальный компилятор откажется компилировать `char* a = "test";` - невежество.

Comment: *"Первая строка обычно не компилируется современными компиляторами"* Она не должна собираться компиляторами С++. А в обычном С строковые литералы до сих пор [имеют](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) тип `char[N]`.

Comment: "не должна" и "обычно не компилируется" - это о разном. То, что в законе (стандарте) написано - это хорошо, но по факту, совсем другое. Есть ещё люди, которые borland c++ 5 используют. И ничего. живут как то.

Comment: *"Я понимаю, что стандарт требует, что бы это не компилировалось."* - так стандарт Си, как раз этого и не требует. Этого требует стандарт С++, но вопрос про Си. Поэтому ваше замечание про *"Первая строка обычно не компилируется"* и не уместно в данном случае.

Comment: оу, я ушел в с++... да, засмотрелся на соседнюю строку.

Answer (score 1):

1. На стеке создаётся указатель, в который копируется **адрес** (инициализируется адресом) символьной строки, которая находится *в области памяти только для чтения*. Используя этот указатель впоследствии, нельзя модифицировать данные, на которые он указывает. Указатель будет автоматически удалён, при выходе из области видимости. Данные на которые он указывал (символьная строка), так и останутся в области памяти доступной только для чтения.
2. На стеке создаётся массив из 6 элементов, в который копируется **символьная строка**, включая завершающий символ `\0`. Элементы массива можно впоследствии изменять, массив будет автоматически уничтожен, при выходе из области видимости.
3. На стеке создаётся массив из 5 элементов, которые инициализируется значениями из списка инициализации. Этот массив так же автоматически удаляется из памяти, при выходе из области видимости.